# How to access a file property from Spring Condition?

Tags: java, spring

Let's say we have a simple Spring [Condition](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.17.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) which has to match against a file property from the properties file:

```
public class TestCondition implements Condition {

  @Override
  public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
    context.getEnvironment().getProperty("my.property");
    context.getBeanFactory().resolveEmbeddedValue("${my.property}");
    context.getEnvironment().resolvePlaceholders("${my.property}");

    // ... more code
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, none of the mentioned above method calls return a real property which is defined in the property file. Instead, I get null when I call the getProperty method and "${my.property}" string for the other two (apparently, the property hasn't been resolved).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `PropertiesLoaderUtils`? Just put it into your method, instead of what you have there.

```
// path to your .properties file
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/my.properties");
Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);

....
String someValue = props.getProperty("someKey", "DEFAULT_VALUE");
```

Maybe try this if your stuff does not work.

Answer (score 0):

you have various ways to access the properties in spring, the main and most simple are as follow

using injected values

```
@PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties")
public class foo {

    @Value("${db.driver}")
    private String dbDriver;
}
```

or you can use the `Environment`

```
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class foo {

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;
  ...
  dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
}
```

more info can be found [here](http://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring)

Comment: I'm not really sure that you can use Autowired and Value annotations inside the Spring Condition. In my case the both resolve to null.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem.
Property was loaded by XML

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:conf/coreConf.properties"/>
```

So I had to add empty java @Configuration to import properties.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:conf/coreConf.properties")
public class Configuration {

}
```

After that I was able to get property

```
@Override
public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
    String property = context.getEnvironment().getProperty("main.settings.db.active");
    return property != null && Boolean.parseBoolean(property.trim());
}
```